# Why are there compile errors when accessing an Enum from the main method?

Tags: java, enums

So i'm a little bit confused as i've never used an enum before. I want to use this enum in my main method. For some reason, i can't (i keep getting errors anytime i even try to do `Status s;` in main). I can however call my `TestingEnum` method from main and of course this works... but i am 100% sure that using the enum this way is just plain wrong. Could someone tell me how i'd go about using this in main properly?

If i try to do: Status s; in my main method, i get this error - "connot find symbol Status s;"

BACKGROUND: new to java and enums...

```
class MyClass {
    public Status s;

    public enum Status {
        STATUS_OPEN(1), 
        STATUS_STARTED(2), 
        STATUS_INPROGRESS(3), 
        STATUS_ONHOLD(4), 
        STATUS_COMPLETED(5), 
        STATUS_CLOSED(6);

        private final int status;

        Status(int stat) {
            this.status = stat;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return this.status;
        }

    }

    private void setStatus(Status stat) {
        s = stat;
    }

    public void TestingEnum() {
        Status myStat = Status.STATUS_ONHOLD;
        setStatus(myStat);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        result.append(NEW_LINE + " Status: " + s + NEW_LINE);

        return result.toString();
    }
}  

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();

        // PROBLEM SETTING STATUS HERE
        // I can't do this:
        Status s;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the actual compilation error messages and the actual code in which it occurs.

Comment: Where you say `Status myStat = Status.ABANDONED;` do you mean `Status.STATUS_ONHOLD`?

Comment: @snim2, yep, sorry! fixed it.

Comment: @Stephen C Ok, i'll updated the question with the error..

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what error you get, because this code, when enclosed inside a class, compiles (except for the usage of Status.ABANDONED, which is not one of the enum constants)

Comment: @ JB Nizet, i fixed that in an update to the question before you posted...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Move the enum to its own class file, or access it with a reference to the enclosing class.**

It looks like you defined the Enum as an inner class of another class.  If you're doing this, you need to access it with the syntax `OuterClass.Status` to access it.  You made it public, so that will work.  You can access it from within the class with no problem because it's contained in the scope of the parent class.

So you can either add the `OuterClass.` before `Status`, or you can move the Enum into its own file like any other class.

Comment: A terminology nitpick: "sub" class and "nested" or "inner" classes are two completely different concepts.

Comment: @ Erick Robertson, so do you mean that in main, i can simply write OuterClass.Status.STARTED?

Comment: @MarkPeters Absolutely correct.  I fixed this in the answer.  Thanks for catching it!

Comment: You were right! I moved it out and life became simple again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the limited code I think the problem is that you try to access

```
public  Status s;
```

which is not static from the static method main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
}
```

Create a instance of your class from main and have a method on that instance use s or declare s as static.

Comment: I do make an instance of the class itself, but even still how do i set the status to something if i can't access status? I'll update the question again with more information..

Comment: Okay, i updated... not sure i quite understand your answer in context to my question...

Comment: Ah, missed that Main was a different class, thought it was main method in MyClass. Eric Robertsson's answer should help you, you need to either move the enum to a class of it's own or reference it with MyClass.Status.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit.  The problem you have is the name of the class is nested and called MyClass.Status

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(); 

   //PROBLEM SETTING STATUS HERE
   //I can't do this:
   MyClass.Status s = MyClass.Status.STATUS_OPEN; 
}
```

BTW: Your IDE should be able to auto fix this mistake.

---

The only compilation error I see is that you have used

```
Status myStat = Status.ABANDONED;
```

without defining it.  I suggest you add this enum or use one you have defined.

Comment: Hmm... i trued your solution just now. I'm not sure why but i still get an error. It says "class file for MyClass$Status not found Error: Cannot find symbol MyClass.Status s = MyClass.Status.STATUS_OPEN;"

Comment: You need to compile MyClass and the class with main at the same time.  Or you could use an IDE which makes doing these things so much easier. I use IntelliJ CE (free)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just instantiate an Enum just before a public class like that. One way to resolve the issues is to have an outer class which will have your Enum class as inner class like this:

```
public class MyStatus {
    static enum Status { 
        STATUS_OPEN(1),  
        STATUS_STARTED(2),  
        STATUS_INPROGRESS(3),  
        STATUS_ONHOLD(4),  
        STATUS_COMPLETED(5),  
        STATUS_CLOSED(6),
        ABANDONED(7);
        private final int status;
        Status(int stat) { 
            this.status = stat;
        }
        public int getStatus() { 
            return this.status; 
        } 
    }
    private Status s;
    public void setStatus(Status stat) {
        s = stat; 
    }
    public void TestingEnum() {
        Status myStat = Status.ABANDONED; 
        setStatus(myStat); 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        result.append(NEW_LINE + " Status: " + s + NEW_LINE);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Also `ABANDONED` wasn't defined so I just added it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by creating a nonstatic enum as outside the class.

```
public enum Status { 
        STATUS_OPEN(1),  
        STATUS_STARTED(2),  
        STATUS_INPROGRESS(3),  
        STATUS_ONHOLD(4),  
        STATUS_COMPLETED(5),  
        STATUS_CLOSED(6),
        ABANDONED(7);
        private final int status;
        Status(int stat) { 
            this.status = stat;
        }
        public int getStatus() { 
            return this.status; 
        } 
    }
```

Created MyStatus class without inner enum block:

```
public class MyStatus {
    private Status s;
    public void setStatus(Status stat) {
        s = stat; 
    }
    public void TestingEnum() {
        Status myStat = Status.ABANDONED; 
        setStatus(myStat); 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        result.append(NEW_LINE + " Status: " + s + NEW_LINE);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Resolved for me.

Answer (score -2):

You would not be able to refer to Status in `main()` because, while Status is `public`, it is not `static`.  You would need to create an instance of your enclosing class and then use it to create an instance of the enum:

```
MyEnclosingClass clz = new MyEnclosingClass();
Status status = clz.new Status();
```

This should resolve the error I believe you are probably getting.

Comment: Inner enums are implicitly static, and even if they aren't your code certainly wouldn't work since you can't create a new enum (that violates the whole point).

Comment: enums are implicitely static. And obviously, you can't call their constructor from the ouside.

Comment: @JBNizet - today I learned.  I must confess I haven't used Enums very much; thanks.